# How to list all resource to secret mappings?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

I am looking for a kubectl command that will list everywhere a secret is referenced.

Example output:

```
deploymentABC - secretkeyname1
deploymentXYZ - secretkeyname2
statefulset123 - secretkeyname1
```

I imagine it could access the `env.from.secret.name` from the yaml?

Comment: Are you specifically restricting it to secrets used as env vars? Because secrets can also be mounted as files (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod).

Comment: @GinoMempin I only use env vars so most interested in that, mounted as files would be a nice to have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all this complicated queries and if you absolutely want to/only can use `kubectl`, you can rely on [Go templates](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) support.

First, define the template (e.g. in a file `list_secrets.tmpl`).

```
{{- range .items}}
    {{- $namespaceAndName := (printf "%s\t%s/%s" .kind .metadata.namespace .metadata.name)}}
    {{- range .spec.template.spec.containers}}
        {{- range .envFrom}}
            {{- $namespaceAndName}}{{- " - "}}{{- .secretRef.name}}{{- "\n"}}
        {{- end}}
    {{- end}}
{{- end}}
```

This iterates over all `envFrom` sections of all containers, and display `namespace/name - secretRefName` if any.

Then, use that template in `kubectl` to format your `Deployment`s and `StatefulSet`s. You could technically pass the template like this: `--o=gotemplate='{{...]}}'`, but I found it rather difficult to read, so I'd rather write it in a separate file (but it's just my opinion).

```bash
kubectl get -A deploy,statefulsets -o=go-template-file=list_secrets.tmpl
```

You should get something like:

```
Deployment      default/app1 - secret1
Deployment      default/app2 - secret1
StatefulSet     default/app3 - secret1
StatefulSet     default/app3 - secret3
```

From there, you can do whatever you want, some examples of what you can achieve below.

#### List only `Deployment`s/`StatefulSet`s with a particular secret

Here, `secret1` for example (see `{{- if eq .secretRef.name "secret1"}}` to check name equality).

```
{{- range .items}}
    {{- $namespaceAndName := (printf "%s\t%s/%s" .kind .metadata.namespace .metadata.name)}}
    {{- range .spec.template.spec.containers}}
        {{- range .envFrom}}
            {{- if eq .secretRef.name "secret1"}}
                {{- $namespaceAndName}}{{- " - "}}{{- .secretRef.name}}{{- "\n"}}
            {{- end}}
        {{- end}}
    {{- end}}
{{- end}}
```

#### Get secrets mounted as volumes

Here, we have to iterate over volumes rather than containers.

```
{{- range .items}}
    {{- $namespaceAndName := (printf "%s\t%s/%s" .kind .metadata.namespace .metadata.name)}}
    {{- range .spec.template.spec.volumes}}
        {{- if .secret }}
            {{- $namespaceAndName}}{{- " - "}}{{- .secret.secretName}}{{- "\n"}}
        {{- end}}
    {{- end}}
{{- end}}
```

#### Get secrets mounted as env vars **and** volumes

This is a mix of the previous solutions; we also add details if the secret is used as env vars or volumes.

```
{{- range .items}}
    {{- $namespaceAndName := (printf "%s\t%s/%s" .kind .metadata.namespace .metadata.name)}}
    {{- range .spec.template.spec.containers}}
        {{- range .envFrom}}
            {{- $namespaceAndName}}{{- " - "}}{{- .secretRef.name}}{{- " (env)\n"}}
        {{- end}}
    {{- end}}
    {{- range .spec.template.spec.volumes}}
        {{- if .secret }}
            {{- $namespaceAndName}}{{- " - "}}{{- .secret.secretName}}{{- " (volume)\n"}}
        {{- end}}
    {{- end}}
{{- end}}
```

This will print:

```
Deployment      default/app1 - secret1 (env)
Deployment      default/app1 - secret1 (volume)
Deployment      default/app2 - secret1 (env)
StatefulSet     default/app3 - secret1 (env)
StatefulSet     default/app3 - secret3 (env)
```